# Obtener datos de un Observable

Tags: typescript, ionic3, observable

he estado estudiando un poco sobre los Observables en Typescript, específicamente en Ionic 3, entiendo que para poder leer los datos de un Observable debo suscribirme a el, pero hasta ahora solo he podido usar los datos dentro del subscribe

```
import { DatabaseProvider from '../../providers/database/database'};
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export interface Data{id:string; name:string; dascription:string;}

export class HomePage{
private Datos: Observable<Data[]>:
datos: any[];

    constructor(private readonly database: DatabaseProvider){
        this.Datos= databse.getDocuments('items');
        this.Datos.subscribe(result => this.datos = result);
        console.log(this.Datos) // el resultado es undefined
    }
}
```

Sin embargo si creo un ***foreach()*** con la variable result y voy imprimiendo los valores dentro del subscribe si me aparecen los datos, alguna idea de como obtenerlos fuera del subscribe

Comment: Lo que sucede es que el observable se está ejecutando en un hilo paralelo. Cuado llegas a la línea: this.Datos.subscribe(result => this.datos = result); Efectivamente ahí se hace la suscripción, pero el programa no se pausa a esperar que el observable emita un valor, el programa simplemente continúa su ejecución y pasa a la siguiente instrucción console.log(this.Datos), en este punto todavía no hay una respuesta del observable y por eso no puedes leer los datos. La manipulación de los datos debes hacerla siempre dentro de la función que se pasó al observable.

Comment: entonces si dentro de la función del subscribe() mando llamar un método diferente y le mando como parámetros mis datos ahí si debería mostrármelos? algo así  this.Datos.subscribe(result => { NewMetodo(valoresDentroDeUnArray)  });  esto podría funcionar??

Comment: Sería así :  this.Datos.subscribe(result => { this.NewMetodo(result); });

Comment: Ok intentare esto solo una duda mas, que tipo de dato debe ser el result,  this.Datos.subscribe(result => { this.NewMetodo(result: ¿tipo? ); });

Comment: Pues no hace falta especificar un tipo de parámetro. El método podría ser así 
NewMetodo(result)
{
//hacer algo con result 
}

Comment: Muchas gracias @crrlos, ya funciono ahora tengo una ultima pregunta, esos datos los asigno a un array: any[]; pero el ngFor no me deja mostrarlos en la vista utilizo un <ion-card *ngFor= "let dato of array"> {{ dato.name }}</ion-card> pero no me lo muestra me podrías ayudar a decirme que es lo que hago mal? gracias de antemano me ha servido mucho tu ayuda

Comment: Tengo que ver el código del .ts y el .html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es que sólo podrás usarlos ahí dentro: Un observable devuelve datos de manera asíncrona, de manera parecida a una promesa. Cuando te subscribes simplemente le estás pasando la función a la que se llamará (en un futuro) cuando emita algo:

```
//defino cómo se procesarán los datos
function funcionObservadora (datos) {
   //proceso los datos recibidos, si se ejecuta este código
   //es porque se ha emitido algo.
}

//me subscribo al observable
miObservable.subscribe(funcionObservadora);
//el observable aún no ha emitido nada
```

Para que entiendas cómo manejar la asincronía: tu constructor lo que hace es *declarar intenciones*, son otros métodos los que tienen que realizar las acciones:

```js
//versión muy simplificada de un Observable

class ObservableMock {
   constructor() {
     this.observers=[];
     this.interval=null;
     this.emitido=0;
   }
   
   subscribe(func) {
     this.observers.push(func);
     if (this.interval==null) {
       this.interval=setInterval(()=>this.emite(),1000);
     }
   }
   
   emite() {
   debugger;
     this.emitido++;
     this.observers.forEach(obs => obs("Emitiendo "+ this.emitido));
     if (this.emitido==5) clearInterval(this.interval);
   }
}

// versión muy simple de un observador: el que observa un observable
class Observador {
  constructor(mock) {
     //subscripción hecha aquí
     mock.subscribe(this.metodoObservador);
  }
  
  //aquí se gestionan los datos recibidos realmente
  metodoObservador(datos) {
    console.log("Recibiendo datos: ",datos);
  }
}

let mock= new ObservableMock();
new Observador(mock);
```

Comment: no entiendo como eso me ayuda con mi problema

Comment: @RaulUrielAndradeSoto la respuesta de Pablo me parece bastante correcta y si ayuda en tu problema, ya que el problema esta en el mal entendido del funcionamiento del subscribe. Manejas el concepto de Promesas?

Comment: no, tengo poco tiempo que retome el crear apps y apenas empece a toparme con estas clases, agradecería si me ayudaran a con un poco de explicación sobre como funcionan mas estas clases

Comment: Te he actualizado la respuesta, a ver si te queda claro