# Subscribe devuelve undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, api, typescript

Cuando hago click por primera vez para logearme el valor de `this.tecnicos` es siempre `undefined`, pero al segundo click ya deja de serlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código es el siguiente:

```
 public login(form: NgForm) {
    let apiAddress: string = `api/Tecnicos/${form.value.email}`;
    this.repository.getData(apiAddress).subscribe(res => {
        this.tecnicos = res as Tecnicos;
      },
      (error) => {
        this.errorHandler.handleError(error);
        this.errorMessage = this.errorHandler.errorMessage;
      }
    )

    if (this.tecnicos.email == form.value.email && this.tecnicos.password == form.value.password) {

      sessionStorage.setItem("email", form.value.email);

      this.obtenerTecnicoLogeado(form.value.email)

    }
    else {
      console.log("Aprendete la pass no-util");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Obtener datos de un Observable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/137413/obtener-datos-de-un-observable)

Comment: El problema no es que no coja los datos, es que los coge siempre al segundo click, y quería saber si hay alguna forma de hacer que lo haga con el primero, ya que no entiendo la diferencia de hacerle un click a hacerle dos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La diferencia no está en que hagas un click o dos:

El código que está dentro del subscribe es el que se ejecuta de manera asíncrona, cuando tienes el dato traído desde backend.

Lo que está fuera, se ejecuta a la vez que se hace la petición (ojo, no cuando se recibe la petición) y por lo tanto no tienes todavía la información.

Sin embargo, cuando el servicio retorna el dato, si que lo guarda en this.tecnicos, ya que está suscrito al resultado. Así que la segunda vez, aunque no hayas recibido el dato de la segunda petición, this.tecnicos tiene el valor de la primera vez que lo llamaste.

Conclusión: si necesitas trabajar con "tecnicos" debes meter toda la lógica dentro del subscribe.