# ¿Como puedo crear un evento personalizado?

Tags: javascript

estoy buscando la forma de crear un evento dentro de una clase, para que cuando lo lance todos los objetos devuelvan un valor para ello lo estoy intentando de la siguiente manera:

```
class clase{
    constructor(){
        this.div = document.createElement("div")
        this.div.addEventListener('eve', function (e) { console.log(`Hola`) }, false);

    }
}
```

Y para lanzarlo desde la consola hago lo siguiente:

```
var event = new Event('eve');

window.dispatchEvent(event)
```

Pero no funciona, alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

Comment: Ese enlace no responde a mi pregunta, yo quiero crear eventos propios y todos los ejemplos son eventros propios del dom, no veo la solucion en niguna de las 4 respuestas

Comment: No es que no se pueda hacer, pero es posible que lo que quieres conseguir sea más fácil de otro modo... ¿Puedes dar un ejemplo más detallado de lo que quieres obtener? Con más perspectiva, no sé si me explico

Comment: Creas un objeto de esa clase
`var objeto = new Clase()` entonces este tendra unos atributos y quieres desde consola que todos esos objetos impriman esos atributos aunque en este caso solo he puesto `Hola`, es decir que igual que haces un onClick programaticamente, lo que quiero es definir mis propios eventos para que los objetos ejecutan ciertas funciones cuando lance dichos eventos desde la consola

Comment: La diferencia es que yo quiero crear un conjunto de eventos, para dar ordenes a estos objetos, el proyecto en el cual me baso es bastante grande quiza algunas cosas no se puedan ver como buenas practicas, pero hay mas detalle intrinseco, pero basicamente el objetivo es que tienes unos objetos y quieres crear unos eventos para que hagan ciertas cosas cuando los lanzas, pero no necesariamente que sean onclick ni nada de eso

Comment: Podrías usar algo como [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/137413/obtener-datos-de-un-observable/137419#137419), creo: un observable con muchos observadores

Comment: No consigo ver como hacer que eso sea util, pero gracias por el intento.

Comment: en la respuesta de PabloLozano cambia los nombres por observador = clase, y ObservableMock = Eventos, si no es eso; deberias de darnos un poco mas de contexto,

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo crear eventos delegados en JavaScript puro?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/110972/c%c3%b3mo-crear-eventos-delegados-en-javascript-puro)

Answer (score 1):

Cuando usamos [element.dispatchEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent), "element" es:

> el objetivo (target en Inglés) del evento.

Entonces, deberías hacer algo como esto:

```js
class clase {
  constructor() {
    this.divs = [document.createElement("div"),
      document.createElement("div"),
      document.createElement("div")
    ];
    this.event = new Event('eve');
    this.divs.forEach(e => {
      e.addEventListener('eve', function(e) {
        console.log(`Hola`)
      });
    })
  }

  dispacher() {
    this.divs.forEach(e => {
      e.dispatchEvent(this.event);//"e" es cada div
    })

  }
}

const a = new clase();
a.dispacher();
```